# Can not connect to SQL express database. "login Failed" error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express, ssms

**The problem:**
I get  the following error when I try to access my web app.
Im running sql express 2008 r2

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

**Background:**
I create my ASPNETDB  in Visual studio via the app data folder. 
I then uploaded the files of my application to my IIS server.
I had no problems, my application was working as expected.

I had the need to attach my DB to SQL server management studio.
I attached the ASPNETDB, however I now get the above error message whenever I try to access my web app.
I don’t know how to rectify this error. Im not very experienced in this.

**What Ive tried:**

I added 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' as a login under
Databases> Security > Logins.

I then added 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' as a user to the particular DB I wanted to connect to
Databases >TheDatabaseIAttached > Sercurity > Users

I still get the same error message.

**my connection string**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks kindly

Comment: Have you explicitly set IIS to run as `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`? Why don't you create a normal Windows login or a SQL auth login to connect to Express? Why do you want to use `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`?

Comment: hmm thanks fo your comment. Yesy Network service was explicitly set in IIS. Im relatively inexperienced with IIS, so Ill look into creating a normal windows login. Thanks again for this insight. I was going down the wrong path previously.